# Wordpress нюансы платных темы

Tags: wordpress, cms, шаблоны

Решил для общего развития освоить `CMS` `wordpress`. Но вот чего конкретно не могу понять касательно платных тем.

Есть ресурсы с платными темами. Что конкретно дает покупка темы? Сколько раз и какие ограничение по установки. Если для единичного продукта то можно ли её отключить на одном продукте и включить на другом?

Как ведет себя тема при правки исходного кода?

Какие вообще бывают лицензии?

Как происходит отслеживание что тема установлена более одного раза.

Посоветуйте где можно смотреть платные темы и на какие аспекты нужно обращать внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покупка темы дает официальное разрешение ее использовать, обновления и поддержку.

Обновления - весьма немаловажный пункт. Приходилось сталкиваться с очень неприятными ошибками в сложном коде темы, которые потом исправлялись авторами в следующем релизе.

Поддержка - тоже полезная вещь, иногда ответ авторов темы на вопрос или исправление их ошибки экономят массу времени.

Обычно разрешена установка темы только на 1 сайт. Для девелоперов, многократно использующих данную тему, отдельные цены. Можно отключить тему на одном сайте и использовать на другом - это не нарушает лицензионные правила.

Тему можно править как угодно, но надо понимать, что при обновлении темы придется правки повторять вручную. Или же выносить все правки в дочернюю тему. Обычно платные темы продаются с заготовкой дочерней темы. Впрочем, создать ее не составляет никакого труда.

Лицензии я видел только для единичного использования и для девелоперов (на ограниченное или неограниченное число сайтов).

Отслеживание - не производится никак. Я многократно покупал или использовал различные купленные темы, копался в коде очень глубоко - и не встречал никаких механизмов отслеживания установки. Технически, можно купленную тему ставить на несколько сайтов и спокойно обновлять ее, все будет работать. Видел прецеденты.

Вопрос об использовании темы скорее юридический, но я ни разу не слышал о таком. При обращении в поддержку авторы часто даже не проверяют, что срок обслуживания уже истек. Тем более никто и никогда не предъявит претензии к установке темы на заведомо тестовом сайте (test.mycoolsite.ru и т.п.)

Самый популярный ресурс для покупки тем сейчас - это themeforest. Имеет очень удобные фильтры для выбора темы. На что обратить внимание? Вот некоторые пункты, которые я учитываю, выбирая тему для клиента:
 1. Wordpress (там еще и для других CMS и просто html есть)
 2. Responsive - современная тема должна быть адаптивной
 3. Software version - WordPress последней или предпоследней версии (есть надежда, что обновят тему под последний WP)
 4. Compatible with - Visual Composer, WooCommerce (если нужен магазин), WPML (если многоязычный сайт)

Далее по вкусу. С этими 4 пунктами все еще около тысячи тем на выбор, проверьте.

Совместимость весьма важна - приходилось не раз мучиться с клиентскими магазинами, созданными на самопальных или бесплатных темах без поддержки WooCommerce, скажем.

И мое глубокое убеждение - новичку надо начинать как раз с платных тем. Их создают достаточно профессиональные команды и код таких тем правильный, соответствующий стандартам WP. Лично я многому научился, разбирая код платных тем.

Comment: Рекомендую включать дебагер и какой--нить мониторинг запросов. Темы с темофортеста - страшное УГ с древними функциями и ошибками. Учиться же разработке надо не у продавцов, а у разработчиков. Т.е. как раз по оф. темам.

Comment: Спасибо.  Ну по тратить 50$ на тему что бы расковырять её в доль и поперек мне не жалко, меня волновало, как раз подъем дев окружения в докере.   Не совсем понял исходя из вашено ответа, если установка ни как не отслеживается, то как понимают кого блокировать?  т.е  я такой покупаю на foo.com  и потом ставлю на bar.com  как авторы понимают кому конкретно отказывать в поддержке? Если тему купили нцать человек, то без привязки к кастомеру любой мог поставить тему на данный домен?

Comment: Да никому они не отказывают. Есть доступ к сайту поддержки? Значит, тема была куплена официально. Не заморачиваются они с доменами, куда тема установлена.

Comment: Многие темы требуют активацию на домене. При этом продолжая работать и без оной. Из неск десятков тем с темофореста видел только  одну, которая после активации давала доп функционал, не доступный без активации. Так что использовать в основном можно где угодно. Но есть разработчики с которыми можно договориться и о работе на тестовых доменах. Говорю же - надо всё узнавать "по месту".

Comment: Подскажите, а можно как то проверить официально был куплен конкретный экземпляр темы или нет?

Comment: @EvgenyL   Неофициальной покупки не бывает ). Если происхождение темы неизвестно, можно предположить наличия в ней любого количества вирусов и/или бэкдоров. Можно попробовать проверить плагинами безопасности, например, WordFence, но лучше не рисковать.

Answer (score 2):

Человеку, только начавшему осваивать ВП покупка тем противопоказана. Особенно на ресурсах типа темофореста и непонятных производителей.

Есть оф. репозиторий (каталог) [бесплатных тем](http://wordpress.org/themes/), с которых и нужно начинать освоение новичку. Многие из этих тем имеют коммерческие версии. Вот их уже можно покупать. [Список доверенных производителей](http://wordpress.org/themes/commercial/) у которых можно покупать темы.

Поясню. В репо попадают темы, прошедшие проверки разного уровня. Код тем открыт и доступен всем, что не только значительно повышает шансы получить помощь по этой теме от коллег, но и даёт немало уверенности в безопасности такой темы (в отличии от коммерческих непонятно кем сделанных).

К сожалению, выбрать подходящую тему довольно непросто не только новичку, но и опытному. На оф форуме я как-то писал [небольшой "мануальчик"](http://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#post-227554) в помощь. Обратите внимание на 4 при оценке внешнего вида и возможностей темы.

Для изменения кода тем без потери возможности обновления в ВП существует механизм [дочерних тем](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не смотря на его актуальность, он абсолютно не о том а чем я спрашивал)))

Comment: Там есть ответы (ссылки) как минимум на 3 вопроса - 1) где можно смотреть платные темы, 2) на какие аспекты нужно обращать внимание. и 3) по правке кода темы. Внимательнее прочитайте и сходите по ссылкам.

Comment: Прежде чем написать, комментарий я разумеется прошелся по ссылкам. Прошу иметь ввиду что основное слово в моем вопросе ПЛАТНАЯ тема. Как что в ВП делается этого в оф доках хватает с избытком. Может я не точно выразился, меня интересует не ГДЕ сколько звездочек а конкретно аспекты связанные с ПЛАТНОЙ частью (лицензии, условия, под кодом я имел ввиду не CSS и HTML а конкретные исходники, php и js  и т д)

Comment: Как раз дочерние темы и служат для внесения изменений в шаблоны темы. http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2
Вопрос по лицензиям просто бессмысленный ибо у каждого разные условия. Читать нужно там, где покупается.

Comment: Что значит бессмысленный? Вот к примеру тема 55738 Я вижу что SPL (одноразовае использование) читаю description и вижу что это лицензия на право использовать тему в одном проекте/домене.  Мне на пример отдавая 114$ не слишком очевидно что я могу конкретно проделать с этой темой, как мне под нею настроить DEV окружение. Как понимает механизм отслеживания что я её установил. Я вот хочу поднять докер с дев окружением, все настроить, после задеплоить. Вот что мне конкретно нужно делать?  Включать отключать тему? VM с докером доступна из внешки.

Comment: >Что значит бессмысленный?

В том, что нет каких-то общих правил для коммерческих тем. Есть правила конкретных ресурсов и производителей.
Если Вас интересует лицензирование на темофоресте - так и надо спрашивать.
Впрочем, повторюсь - спрашивать нужно там (у тех), где покупается. Никто, кроме продавцов и разработчиков не даст более достоверного ответа.