# Ошибка во всех темах при работе с Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте, недавно начал работать с Wordpress

Создаю стартовые темы для разработки через https://underscores.me/

Во всех темах есть одна ошибка:

"uasort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему это возникает и как можно исправить?

Comment: C underscores не сам придумал, на канале парень использует и видео за 2017-2018, но спасибо за напутствие

Comment: Во-первых, это не ошибка, а предупреждение. А в главных, более старый и бесполезный код, чем underscores, найти сложно. Заканчивайте тратить свое время впустую. Берите любую современную тему из репозитория WordPress, или стандартную twentysenteen, учитесь создавать от неё дочернюю тему и постепенно, шаг за шагом, меняйте функционал под себя.

Comment: В 2018 делать видео уроки на основании underscores уже просто неприлично.

Comment: Потому что не нужно использовать разный хлам  (видеоуроки в тч). а нужно читать мануалы, брать темы из оф каталога и делать к ним дочерние. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614157

Comment: Понял, принял, большое спасибо всем за напутствия и советы.